# Google fonts not working in 2 of 5 browsers

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

Good afternoon. I am very new to this community and this is my first question here. I've been learning HTML and CSS for the past month and I've come across my first situation where I haven't been able to find an answer on this awesome site! (I'm found a few questions and answers but nothing specific to my situation so your assistance would be greatly appreciated)

I am using Notepad++ to write a website and have the following included in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
```

and then in the CSS I have:

```
font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
```

Now the reason I am so confused is because the font loads perfectly on Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not in IE or Firefox?! As i said I cannot find a specific answer to this question so anything I've missed that you can point out would be much appreciated. Do google fonts not work on IE or Firefox locally maybe??

Thanks again

Shane

UPDATE: I am using the latest version of all the browsers; I just downloaded Firefox and IE today.

Comment: Have you tried another Google Web font to see if it works with an alternate? So strange if it does not work for some fonts. But I guess possible.

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference, but have you tried the Javascript approach to loading the webfont?

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a webserver? By locally, this means that you get a url that starts with `file://`

Comment: Yes, running Locally - would that stop it working in IE and Firefox?
Thanks Gohn I will try that later.

Comment: Not sure actually. I'm testing it out right now.

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox and IE using a local html file

Comment: I responded to Prisoners thread saying I'm having the same issue with another completely different font! I am in Thailand. Perhaps they have something disabled. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Have you checked your console in Firefox for errors?

Comment: I got this: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. Iron%20Legend.html
22:11:55.898 Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@import'. IL%20style.css:11

Comment: and this: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Frijole" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/frijole/v3/JMJmIdqpEk7-RyNfk_4Nrw.woff

Comment: Maybe set charset to `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your `head` section

Comment: Yeah I was concerned about the `cross site access issue` which I had encountered in FF before. But never happened with Google Webfonts. Oh well, maybe see if the charset meta tag fixes the first error first.

Comment: Lol that's the first thing I fixed. As I said I'm quite new to this.

I think the problem was the downloadable font: download failed part. 
What does that mean bad URI or cross-site access not allowed?

Comment: I was going to take this to chat, but you don't have enough rep yet. Hehe.

Comment: I tried that too but it wouldn't let me - just signed up today. Thanks for your assistance Gohn. A quick google search tells me I'd need to add something at the server end. Which obviously I cannot do right? Therefore I cannot fix this problem. But why did the font display correctly for yourself and others?

Comment: Thanks Gohn I just joined your chat link

Answer (score 1):

That's because this fond is only providing a `woff` file:

```
src: local('Tangerine'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/tangerine/v4/HGfsyCL5WASpHOFnouG-RLO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
```

You need their other browser alternatives, such as `svg`, `eot`. Although in most modern browsers, it'll work fine - there are browsers and versions that don't [support](http://caniuse.com/woff) it. If the two browsers you've tested in say they have support, then we'd need a test page that we can look at.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that in my question. I just downloaded all the browsers today so they are the latest versions.

Comment: @NZGamma - in that case, it works fine for me in Firefox on OSX using this: http://jsfiddle.net/L9DBG/ - check this link and see if it works in your browsers, if it does, you must have conflicting rules or another issue.

Comment: thank you again. I just opened that link in Firefox and the hello is displaying as default text still :S
Could it some sort of software issue on my computer?

Comment: @NZGamma, I suppose it could be an issue with your local version of that font file - try removing it and see if the issue is resolved?

Comment: Yeah, I tested the JS Fiddle in both IE11 and FF on Windows 7 and it displayed fine for me.

Comment: Ok guys I just tried another completely different font (Frijole) and that font also is not showing up in IE or Firefox either. So it was not the font specifically, but the browsers. As i said they are the latest versions. I am in Thailand currently, perhaps Thailand's web restrictions are causing an issue???

Comment: @NZGamma, if that were the case it'd be the same on all browsers

Comment: Bizarre. This is frustrating me greatly. I'm confused even more now that another font is having the same issue on IE AND Firefox, but not the other three.